# ASP.Net WebForms| Show text only to login users?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So. i got a website in asp.net webforums, the thing is.

i can easyley control who can look to each pages with :

```
<location path="seetalktous.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="admin"/>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

the thing is, what can i do if i want a page to be seen to normal users, but only a text line will be showed to login ones, or only button will be showed to a user(admin) how can i do that?

thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [LoginView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx) control. [Read this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178338%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to see how to use the Rolegroups property to provide a template for a group.

Comment: This is nice! its works and everyting, but!how can i do that it will show text only to one user?:)like, only to admin?

Comment: Two ways: put that user in a separate role (users can be in multiple roles) or store the text per user (e.g. in a database) and retrieve the text per user. Do not put user names in your code; that would make your application very hard to maintain.

Comment: How can i use role?, i got visual sutido 2010 :).

Comment: In visual studio (when the ASP.NET project is open) click the menu Project and then ASP.NET Configuration. Read more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228053.aspx Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

What about the following code in the relevant event handler

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
  // do something for authenticated users
} else {
  // do something for users who are not authenticated
}
```